# Search value in php array ($_COOKIE)

Tags: php

for a persistent connection function, I want to test the presence of fb's cookies, I tried:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $_COOKIE ); $i++ ) {
    $tt = preg_match("/fbsr_/i", $_COOKIE[$i], $value );
    if ( $tt == 1 ) {
        echo "resultat found : $value";
        break;
    }
}
```

But it's not the correct syntax so, which is it? I have "Undefined index" and "Undefined offset" errors.

Comment: I think that you have to look into the key, for example your key is $i,  your preg_match should check the name of the cookies not the values, a quickly look into the inspect element, show taht the $_COOKIE['c_user'] represent the facebook session

Comment: Use array_keys() and preg_grep() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_COOKIE is not indexed array, but associative one, use:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $Ckey => $Cvalue) {
    $tt = preg_match("/fbsr_/i", $Ckey, $value); // not very sure what you want to check: either cookie name - $Ckey, if cookie value - use $CValue here
    if ($tt == 1) {
        echo "resultat found : $value";
          break;
    }
}
```

note - you're trying to save something in variable $value - it will contain `fbstr_` only when found, I suppose you will need $Cvalue variable from my loop

Comment: Just a small note: The OP is not trying to evaluate against the key.